# Calculate variance on not normal distributed groups

Tags: variance

Is there a way to calculate if the variances of two groups are equal when one of the groups is not normal distributed?

Comment: Levene's Test and the Brown-Forsythe Test.

Comment: [Nonparametric test for equality of variances](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/278222/nonparametric-test-for-equality-of-variances)